# Is "grammered" a word?

Tags: meaning, etymology, is-it-a-word, past-participles, morphology

Can I get any details about the word *grammered*? Is there any relation between it and "grammatically corrected" or "grilled and hammered"?

Comment: Where have you seen it? The OED has citations for the verb _grammered_ from 1593, 1625, 1682 and 1883, but I don’t suppose they’re the ones you have in mind.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, source is myself. I used this word as a short for grammatically corrected. But I found a site showing second one as it's meaning. I'm seeking for the validity of this word.

Comment: There's a difference between *grammered* and *grammared*, as the two current answers demonstrate.

Comment: No, it's not a word in contemporary standard English. It might have been used in the past, and it might be a very informal neologism, but the great majority of people would not know what you're talking about if you used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *grammared* is a word.

[Verbix](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/grammar.html): **grammar** Infinitive: *to grammar*; Participle: *grammared*; Gerund: *grammaring*

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammared): **grammared** Having a specified style of grammar.

In the pedagogical world, the concept of *grammaring* has been put forward with a clear definition.

Even otherwise, if a person is equipped with literary skills, we say the person is *lettered*. By analogy, one who has acquired grammatical skills would naturally be a *grammared person*.

Learning & Using Grammar:
[ihjournal](http://ihjournal.com/teaching-language-from-grammar-to-grammaring): … grammar is not a list of rules which can be applied to any sentence regardless of the context of use. Successful communication is marked by a skill in exploiting the grammatical resource to match the meaning. This skill is **grammaring**, the dynamic process of relating form and structure to meaningful units.

In Linguistics, Computational Linguistics:
Developing a 'grammar'.

Slang/ Informal:
[UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Grammared): -> **grammared** Whilst on Facebook or other websites you notice an error in spelling and thus correct it due to sheer awesomeness of the language you speak/know. Similar to out-grammared except it sounds better.
-> **grammared** What gingers say instead of "proof reading".

Also something your parents may do on a daily basis when you are younger (*Grammarize*, *grammaticize*).

---

Usage examples:
(Charles A. Moore) *English is a **loose-grammared** language compared to Greek and Latin.*
(From the Scottish Christian Journal) *From the time of his landing at Macao, in 1807, till his death in August 1834, he **grammared** the language in as far as it could be grammared ; he translated, in conjunction with Milne, the whole Scriptures ; he printed and circulated innumerable sermons and tracts* …